# Как правильно использовать document.getElementsByClassName в react?

Tags: reactjs

Хотел прямо в `constructor` нужные элементы объявить (`this.runner`). Однако, получаю `undefined`, что логично, элемент еще не создан. Можно создать вспомогательную функцию, в которой объявлять нужные элементы, то это какая-то кривая затея. А как правильно это сделать?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.runner = document.getElementsByClassName('slider__runner')[0];

  }

  getElement() {
    this.runner = document.getElementsByClassName('slider__runner')[0];

  }

  onClick(event) {
    console.clear();

    // Получу undefined
    console.log(this.runner);

    this.getElement();

    // Получу нужный элемент
    console.log(this.runner);
    this.runner.style.left = `${event.nativeEvent.offsetX - this.runner.offsetWidth / 2}px`

  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="slider">
        <div 
          onClick = {event => {this.onClick(event)}}
          className="slider__range"
        >
          <div className="slider__runner" / >
        </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.slider {
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

.slider__range {
  position: relative;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

.slider__runner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #0094ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Правильно — не использовать. Насколько я помню, это противоречит самой сути реакта

Comment: Как в данному случае сделать так, чтобы все работало тогда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сработало:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slider__runner')[0]
```

Необходимо это делать после того как загружено DOM дерево, для этого можно воспользоваться методом: componentDidMount

```
class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.runner = document.getElementsByClassName('slider__runner')[0]
    }

    ....
}
```

Но объектом document лучше не пользоваться. У React есть ref, который предоставляет доступ к узлам DOM дерева или элементам React.

Воспользуйтесь документацией: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Igor рад помочь:)